# how to fix a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id='countdown'></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
  var elementPosition = $('#countdown').offset();

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
          $('#countdown').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0'});
    } else {
        $('#countdown').css('position','static');
    }    
  });
</script>
```

This code is working on JSFiddle, but when I tried it, it didn't work for me.

I tried looking on the console (developer's view) and it's pointing on `elementPosition.top` . However, `top` is unknown property. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Also see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I could see is the code is not in a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function () {
    var elementPosition = $('#countdown').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('#countdown').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0'
            });
        } else {
            $('#countdown').css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() { .... });` to make sure all of your elements inside the DOM have been loaded properly before executing your javascript code

```
$(function() {
    var elementPosition = $('#countdown').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
            $('#countdown').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0'});
        } else {
            $('#countdown').css('position','static');
        }    
    });
});
```

Your code works in `jsFiddle` because `jsFiddle` has already done that part for you.